# Identify who took new free space each day

Tags: windows, configuration, memory, disk-space-utilization

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2. I am hosting my development database server there. Last week I truncated many tables and did a shrink database to free up some space. And I had obtained around 60GB free space. Now free space is getting decreased around 5GB every day (15GB in 3 days).

I would like to know who is taking this much space every day. It is not the database transactions – because I don’t have many transactions in my development database. Is there a way to get who claimed “new” free space each day?

Please be clear that I am NOT looking for memory used by each application. What I am looking for is who took “new” free space each day.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a tool such as http://diskreport.net to get a periodic report of your disk space usage, and then find where space has grown between two reports.